# Elasticsearch analyser only being used when I specify the field of the search

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I have an analyser called `autocomplete_analyser` defined on a field `name`. When I run the query

```
http://localhost:9200/courses/course/_search?q=name:dav&pretty=true
```

it runs the analyser and returns the correct results. When I run

```
http://localhost:9200/courses/course/_search?q=dav&pretty=true
```

it does not.

How can I make ES run the analyser without me specifying the fields being searched on?
I need to use this analyser across a number of fields so its important that I can search all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, queryString queries are applied on _all field which have its own analyzer.

You can define your specific analyzer for the _all field using the Put Mapping API.

Does it help?